# Haml form_for drop-down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

I cant show drop down list in my view.
Here is my form for edit action.

```
= form_for @question do |w|
  %p
    = w.select :name => "question_status"
    %option{:value => 1}= label 1
    %option{:value => 2}= label 2      
  %p
    = w.submit "Update"
  %p
    = link_to 'Back', :back
```

I have this error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
= form_for @question do |w|
  %p
    %select{ :name => "question[question_status]" }
      %option{:value => 1}= "label 1"
      %option{:value => 2}= "label 2"      
  %p
    = w.submit "Update"
  %p
    = link_to 'Back', :back
```

Comment: edit.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'

Comment: change to this `
    = w.select "question_status"
    %option{:value => 1}= "label 1"
    %option{:value => 2}= "label 2"`

wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: Tested on my own real example and corrected `select` line. Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
w.select :question_status, @question.map {|q| [q.label,q.value] }
```

or if you want to make it static

```
w.select :question_status, [['label1',value],['label2',value]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you, Let me know the concerns.

```
= form_for @question do |w|
  %p
    = w.select "question_status", [["1", "label 1"], ["2", "label_2"]]
  %p
    = w.submit "Update"
  %p
    = link_to 'Back', :back
```