# haml. dropdown lias in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

I trying:

```
= form_for @question do |w|
  %p
    = w.select "question_status"
    %option{:value => 1}= "label 1"
    %option{:value => 2}= "label 2"
```

but get : **wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [HAML. form\_for. dropdowsn list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956429/haml-form-for-dropdowsn-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= form_for @question do |w|
  %p
    = w.select 'question_status', [['label 1', 1], ['label 2', 2]]
```